# Cron doesn't run cron task in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I'm trying to run a script in a Docker container with cron. It looks like the script isn't being run at all at first. `crontab -l` shows the task. `service cron reload` doesn't fix the issue. If I do `crontab -e`, add a space and save the file, it suddenly works. So I can rule out permission issues etc.

```
FROM node:17

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

COPY scripts /app/scripts
COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN chmod -R +x /app/scripts

WORKDIR /app
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN npm install

RUN echo "* * * * *  /usr/local/bin/node /app/scripts/test.js >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

CMD ["cron","-f"]
```

Comment: Perhaps this might shed some light: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478968/can-i-manually-create-and-edit-var-spool-cron-crontabs-t-without-crontab-e

Comment: Thank you, Adding ```RUN crontab -u root /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root``` fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RUN crontab -u root /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` after creating the file seems to have fixed it.